# Windows 10 adds keyboard on startup which I do not wish to use

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

### Background

I'm using Windows 10 English version. Usually I'm using Polish or English.

I've configured:

- Polish language with keyboard layout "Polish (programmers)"
- English language with keyboard layout "Polish (programmers)"

Note that "Polish (programmers)" is equivalent to US keyboard layout, but some letters can be altered with <kbd>Alt</kbd>: `żźęąółćś`.

### Problem

System do not respect my settings. It works after I change settings, but restarting computer leads to state where I can see more keyboards then I configured:

[image: Language settings]

When opening configuration of polish language I see this:

[image]

Note system tray shows two keyboard layouts polish language ("Polish (programmers)", "United States-International"). On other hand langue preferences for polish shows only one keyboard ("Polish (programmers)").

### Workaround

To recover from this error I have to add (in langue polish preferences) keyboard show in system tray and the remove it.

What is funny this adds `US QWERTY` keyboard for English language.
Again it is not listed in English settings, so I'm adding this keyboard and removing it. Then I have desired configuration until next computer restart.

This is annoying since quite often I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> what switches this keyboards and forces me to restore desired configuration.

How can I fix it permanently?